# Python Date Comparisons

Tags: python, datetime

I would like to find out if a particular python datetime object is older than X hours or minutes. I am trying to do something similar to:

```
if (datetime.now() - self.timestamp) > 100
# Where 100 is either seconds or minutes
```

This generates a type error.

What is the proper way to do date time comparison in python? I already looked at [WorkingWithTime](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WorkingWithTime) which is close but not exactly what I want. I assume I just want the datetime object represented in seconds so that I can do a normal int comparison.

Please post lists of datetime best practices.

Comment: `datetime.now()` (or other local time given as a *naive* datetime object) may fail around DST transitions or changes in UTC offset for the local timezone for other reasons. UTC time or an aware datetime object should be used instead e.g., `datetime.utcnow()` or `datetime.now(timezone.utc).astimezone()`.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Use the `datetime.timedelta` class:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> then = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours = 2)
>>> now = datetime.now()
>>> (now - then) > timedelta(days = 1)
False
>>> (now - then) > timedelta(hours = 1)
True
```

Your example could be written as:

```
if (datetime.now() - self.timestamp) > timedelta(seconds = 100)
```

or

```
if (datetime.now() - self.timestamp) > timedelta(minutes = 100)
```

Answer (score 5):

Compare the difference to a timedelta that you create:

```
if datetime.datetime.now() - timestamp > datetime.timedelta(seconds = 5):
    print 'older'
```

Answer (score 5):

Alternative:

```
if (datetime.now() - self.timestamp).total_seconds() > 100:
```

Assuming self.timestamp is an datetime instance

Comment: It's worth mentioning that total_seconds() is available since Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of the 'days' and 'seconds' attributes of the returned object to figure out the answer, like this:

```
def seconds_difference(stamp1, stamp2):
    delta = stamp1 - stamp2
    return 24*60*60*delta.days + delta.seconds + delta.microseconds/1000000.
```

Use abs() in the answer if you always want a positive number of seconds.

To discover how many seconds into the past a timestamp is, you can use it like this:

```
if seconds_difference(datetime.datetime.now(), timestamp) < 100:
     pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract two [datetime](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-datetime.html) objects to find the difference between them.
You can use `datetime.fromtimestamp` to parse a POSIX time stamp.

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
# self.timestamp should be a datetime object
if (datetime.now() - self.timestamp).seconds > 100:
    print "object is over 100 seconds old"
```

Comment: I don't think this works. The seconds attribute for a timedelta http://docs.python.org/lib/datetime-timedelta.html is limited to 1 day so if your length of time is longer than 1 day it will be inaccurate

Comment: all that you would have to do is compare it with another timedelta instead of the seconds attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your time delta into seconds and then use conversion back to hours elapsed and remaining minutes.

```
start_time=datetime(
   year=2021,
   month=5,
   day=27,
   hour=10,
   minute=24,
   microsecond=0)

 end_time=datetime.now()
 delta=(end_time-start_time)

 seconds_in_day = 24 * 60 * 60
 seconds_in_hour= 1 * 60 * 60

 elapsed_seconds=delta.days * seconds_in_day + delta.seconds

 hours=  int(elapsed_seconds/seconds_in_hour)
 minutes= int((elapsed_seconds - (hours*seconds_in_hour))/60)

 print("Hours {} Minutes {}".format(hours,minutes))
```